# Extend an object with same name tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have an object

```
$a = {'fruit' :
    { 'name' : 'apple', 'cost' : '5.00' }
}
```

and another object

```
$b = {'fruit' :
    { 'name' : 'pear', 'cost' : '4.00' }
}
```

How can I use jQuery or any JS library to make 2 copies of the same object in my result object? I.e. I would like the final object to be

```
$basket = {'basket' :
    {'fruit' :
        { 'name' : 'pear', 'cost' : '4.00' }
    },
    {'fruit' :
        { 'name' : 'apple', 'cost' : '5.00' }
    }
}
```

However, jQuery libraries only merge the 2nd object's properties into the first.

Comment: You have wrong syntax in `$basket` definition

Comment: Invalid JSON. You might mean `"basket":[$a,$b]`

Comment: Use array for basket, and push the fruits there.

Comment: You are missing a quote after 'cost

Comment: That's not legal JS syntax. You should really learn some JS fundamentals.

Comment: made changes to the cost

Comment: @Leo: It's just a typo, add the `'` after `cost` and it's valid syntax.

Comment: @Leo: Yes. You can put property names in either single or double quotes (or no quotes at all, provided the names are valid property name literals -- no spaces, etc.). You may be thinking of JSON, which is more restrictive. It's also valid (in loose mode) to not declare a variable explicitly, though I call it *The Horror of Implicit Globals* because, well, it's horrible to create implicit globals. :-) And automatic semicolon insertion kicks in to handle the missing `;` after the assignment statements.

Comment: @Leo: You should have been clear what you were referring to. :-) Yes, of course the last one isn't valid; the question is asking how to do it! If they knew how to do it, they wouldn't need to ask, would they?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP doesn't even know language fundamentals required for what he wants to do. That's why my answer is to learn fundamentals. In such situation, one is not likely to understand why working code is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two properties with the same name on a single object; you could have a single property with an *array* of values, though.

If you want to build it from your `$a` and `$b` variables:

```js
var $a = {
  'fruit': {
    'name': 'apple',
    'cost': '5.00'
  }
};

var $b = {
  'fruit': {
    'name': 'pear',
    'cost': '4.00'
  }
};

var $basket = {
  'fruit': [$a.fruit, $b.fruit]
};

snippet.log($basket.fruit[0].name); // apple
snippet.log($basket.fruit[1].name); // pear
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

If you want to just declare the basket without `$a` and `$b`:

```js
var $basket = {
  'fruit': [
    {
      'name': 'apple',
      'cost': '5.00'
    },
    {
      'name': 'pear',
      'cost': '4.00'
    }
  ]
};

snippet.log($basket.fruit[0].name); // apple
snippet.log($basket.fruit[1].name); // pear
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: You don't need the `'` around the property names in your object initializers, as they fit the rules for property name literals (but the `'` are harmless).

Side note 2: If you want your values for `cost` to be numbers, you don't want `'` around them.

Side note 3: Note that I've added `var` before the variable names. Your code was falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), creating **global** variables (not local ones as in PHP) because it didn't declare them.

Side note 4: It's not usual practice in JavaScript code to prefix variables with a `$`. You *can*, but it's not common practice, except that some people do it when using jQuery to indicate that the variable refers to a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Object property labels should be unique. Create an object where property `basket` is an array of [fruit] objects and you can iterate the basket for . Example:

```js
var a = {'fruit' :
           { name : 'apple', cost : 5.00 },
          'misc' :
           { name: 'decorative fruit basket', cost: 7.89 }    
        };
var b = {'fruit' :
    { name : 'pear', cost : 4.00 }
}

var c = {basket: [a, b]};
var result = document.querySelector('#result');

result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(c, null, ' ');

var i = c.basket.length;
while (i--) {
  if (c.basket[i].fruit.name === 'pear') {
    result.innerHTML += '\n**Found pear, cost is: '+ c.basket[i].fruit.cost.toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll need a list of items (as your Basket).
Check this out:

```
{
  "basket": [
    {
      "fruit": {
        "name": "pear",
        "cost": "4.00"
      }
    },
    {
      "fruit": {
        "name": "apple",
        "cost": "5.00"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can play around with the JSON Schema Generator: http://jsonschema.net/ - it checks for validity and more importantly generates a schema that you can use to validate your objects.

The others also pointed out, that your data structure might need some rethinking. You could e.g. store the fruits' names as key for a dictionary entry, like this:

```
{
  "basket": [
    {
      "pear": "4.00"
    },
    {
      "apple": "5.00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Exemplary, this gives the following Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "/",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "basket": {
      "id": "basket",
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "0",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "pear": {
              "id": "pear",
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, try to get on terms with a tool like jsonlint or even jslint, that helps to avoid a lot of frustration, because those are better suited to tell you about problems in your code than e.g. a browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var a = {
  "fruit": {
    "name": "apple",
    "cost": "5.00"
  }
};

var b = {
  "fruit": {
    "name": "pear",
    "cost": "4.00"
  }
};

var basket = {};

basket[0] = a;
basket[1] = b;

/*

// `basket`

{
    "0": {
        "fruit": {
            "name": "apple",
            "cost": "5.00"
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "fruit": {
            "name": "pear",
            "cost": "4.00"
        }
    }
}
*/

document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0]
.innerText = JSON.stringify(basket, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```